# Form load entity by input and add not found error message to specific field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.6

Want to load a user entity by form input field when not exist add a error message to the field

```
    $builder->setMethod('get');
    $builder->add('username', 'text'); // add error to this field when username dont exist
    $builder->add('token', 'text') // add error on this field when token dont match with current token
        // transformer should set token to null
        ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
            function ($original) {
                return $original;
            },
            function ($submitted) {
                return null;
            }
        ));
    $builder->add('submit', 'submit');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class User
{
    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Name is empty")
     */
    protected $name;
}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html

I am not sure where you are checking for `token`. Do not forget to add `$form->isValid()` after `$form->handleReqest($reqest)`